# What honorifics and forms of address were appropriate for 17th century Spanish nobility?

Tags: cultural-history, names, royalty

My world has a country that is based in quite a few regards on Spain during the 17th/18th century. I would like the readers to feel the honor and prestige of that culture by accurately mimicking Spanish honorifics.

One of the characters in this country has gained a title for service done to the country, and the royal family. (basically becoming count, duke or whatever title I decide on) of their hometown.

What I am looking for is a formal way to address this character, that would not insult or misrepresent the Spanish culture. For example, it would be embarrassing to write a story about a knighted person in a Britain-based society and have a dialogue that failed to use the title 'Sir' or 'Dame' correctly.

Spanish culture generally grants people two surnames, honoring both parents and following this formula: [*Given name*][*Surname of Father*][*Surname of Mother*]

My idea is, by adding this title—let's say 'count' for the sake of argument—this person may then be styled [*Given Name*][*Surname Father*][*Surname Mother*], Count of [*name of hometown*], or simply [*Given Name*], Count of [*name of hometown*].

I have been looking around on the Web, the rules I have found for formal address, especially for nobility, is a bit confusing. They seem to differ depending on the source, so I hope someone here can help me figure out something that is at least not disrespectful.

Comment: Something to consider is _who is speaking_: there may be _official_ forms of address, but that doesn't mean everybody uses them. You won't see many people referring to "Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II, by the Grace of God, of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms and Territories Queen, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith". Nor, for that matter, is the former leader of Cuba frequently referred to as "Fidel Alejandro Castro Ruz".

Comment: You'll probably get better answers for the correct form of address at [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), even for historic ones: see e.g. [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221501/19th-c-forms-of-address).

Comment: It looks like you're asking a question about character building rather than worldbuilding. As a general rule questions about how to name things aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: This question is about the proper use of honorifics and forms of address. This is very much a worldbuilding problem: Honorifics and forms of address are important parts of culture. Inappropriate addresses may ruin the immersion and/or offend the readers.

Comment: @Otkin I'm not one who supports a blanket ban on questions for naming things. But this question doesn't do any worldbuilding in my view. It's just research into real life forms of address combining patronymics with titles. There's no unique context given that makes this world different from the Spain example, so this is either a plain English language question, or a history question if a contemporary 17th-century FoA is sought after.

Comment: (1) Titles, names and forms of address are very very different things. For example, in English, the Queen is properly addressed as "Your Majesty" (first time) and then "Ma'am". Her *name* is not H. Majesty or Ma'am; and her formal *title* is very long. (2) Forms of address in Spain, **when**? The 1400s, the 1700s, early 20th century, late 20th century, today?

Comment: @AlexP Actually the when is in the question: 17th/18th century. I still think that this is a factual research question that should go on either History SE or English SE.

Answer (score 5):

A good primary source for the honorifics and the forms of adress of the Spanish nobility from the Siglo de Oro (the Golden Century, the period you are asking for) is the several plays by Calderón de la Barca and Lope de Vega.

From them, the rules are more or less:

- All nobility gets a *Don/Doña* before the name, even the *hidalgos*
  (the lowest of nobility). If you are writing in English, maybe that
  "*Don*" looks weird. It comes from the Latin *dominus/domina*
  (master/mistress), so maybe you want to change it to Lord/Lady.
- The usual adress to the nobility is *señor/señora*, *gran señor/señora*
  sometimes for the higher nobles. *Excelencia* is reserved for dukes,
  princes and kings. With the times, lower titles added an
  *Ilustrísimo*.
- So, Fernando Álvarez de Toledo (1595-1667), Duke of Alba would be in Spanish: *Excelentísimo Señor D. Fernando Álvarez de Toledo y Mendoza, Duque de Alba*
- Cayetano Rebolledo (1665-1692), Marquis of Lazán would be in Spanish: *Ilustrísimo Señor D. Cayetano Rebolledo de Palafox y Martínez de Marcilla, Marqués de Lazán*
- The two family names are always separated by the "y". During the 16th century, the first family name wasn't always the father's and even siblings could have changed family names. This was more uncommon during the 18th century but it wasn't regulated until the second half of the 19th century.
- Unlike a common misconception, the "explosion" of given names some Spaniards got (two common names + a common name given by the godfather + a common name by the godmother + a beloved saint or the saint of the birthday) wasn't usual until almost 1800. Even nobles only had one given name (two at the most).

Comment: This text reads better as paragraphs than in bullet points

Answer (score 3):

While the commonest Spaniard will have to do with just a name (that can be a complex compound one) followed by a paternal surname and a maternal surname (nowadays the order can be changed), aristocrats tend to spouse extremely long multiple first names followed by a plethora of surnames and family names.

For example, the current duchess of Alba is **Eugenia Brianda Timotea Cecilia** (4 names) **Martínez de Irujo** (first, very aristocratic, surname) **y Fitz-James Stuart** (second, and even posher, surname), daughter of **María del Rosario Cayetana Fitz-James Stuart y Silva**, the former duchess. She is normally known as *Eugenia Martínez de Irujo*, while her mother was universally called *Cayetana de Alba* (first name + title). Similarly, one of the nephews of the current king of Spain, Philip VI, is called **Felipe Juan Froilán de Todos los Santos de Marichalar y Borbón** although he is normally just called Froilán, given that there must be less than 10 people in the whole country with that uncommon name.

For the XVII/XVIII centuries the usual custom would be referring to the current owner of the title by a combo of *name + title*, where the name would be the one the person liked the most or that his/her family used the most, while the other relatives would be referred as *name + surname*, where the surname used would usually correspond to the branch of the family ostenting most important title, whether it comes from the paternal or maternal branch (a duke takes precedence over a count or marquis).

Comment: Not just aristocrats. Obvious example: Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso. His father had aristocratic ancestors, but Picasso's background was firmly middle class.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Yes, there's no law preventing commoners to have 7 or 8 first names; it's just not common.